# Как найти все элементы с одинаковым атрибутом

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Как найти все теги с одинаковым  атрибутом **spinner** и заменить им ***всем*** значение этого атрибута.

В моем примере монтаж происходит только у первого атрибута как сделать чтобы сработало на всех тегах с этим атрибутом ?

И если можно еще пример на coffeescript

```js
i = 0;
tags = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
tag = null;


replacementAttr = function() {
      var image;
      while ( tag = tags[i++]) {
        if (this.tag.getAttribute('spinner') != null) {
          image = tag.getAttribute('spinner');
          tag.style.backgroundImage = "url( " + image + " )";
          return;
        }
      }
    };
    
    replacementAttr();
```

```css
div{
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #d7d7d7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div spinner="http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/394424921_1280x720.jpg">spinner</div>
<div spinner="http://www.fiji.travel/sites/default/files//styles/hero-full/public/sports-illustrated-fiji-banner.jpg?itok=v4WCGsHC">spinner</div>
<div spinner="http://fanaticsview.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/hannah-daviss-si-swimsuit-2016-s.jpg">spinner</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

оказалось что все дело в **return** и **i**

```js
i = 0;
tags = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
tag = null;


replacementAttr = function() {
      var image;
      while (i <  tags.length) {
        tag = tags[i]
        if (tag.getAttribute('spinner') != null) {
          image = tag.getAttribute('spinner');
          tag.style.backgroundImage = "url( " + image + " )";
        }
        i++
      }
    };
    
    replacementAttr();
```

```css
div{
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #d7d7d7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div spinner="http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/394424921_1280x720.jpg">spinner</div>
<div spinner="http://www.fiji.travel/sites/default/files//styles/hero-full/public/sports-illustrated-fiji-banner.jpg?itok=v4WCGsHC">spinner</div>
<div spinner="http://fanaticsview.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/hannah-daviss-si-swimsuit-2016-s.jpg">spinner</div>
```